# Adiciona consulta WITH dentro de outra consulta

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Galera, como adicionar a consulta abaixo como uma subconsulta.

Consulta com `WITH`:

```
WITH tabela (projeto, operadora) AS (
  SELECT p.projdesc,
         tt.tartitulo
    FROM tarefa tt

         INNER JOIN projetos p ON p.projid = tt.projid
         LEFT JOIN tipo c ON c.tipid = tt.tartipid
   WHERE tt.modid = 181
     AND tt.tarstatus <> 9

     AND (tt.tartipid BETWEEN 867 AND 934
      OR tt.tartipid IN (1004, 1034))
     AND c.tipdescricao LIKE 'Habilita%')

SELECT r.projeto,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t.operadora
                FROM tabela t
               WHERE t.projeto = r.projeto

                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS operadoras
  FROM tabela r
 GROUP BY projeto;
```

Outra Consulta, onde nessa é para colocar a consulta de cima, pois será gerada outra coluna com a `query` acima.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(pp.projdesc),
               c.compdesc qtdecnpjs,
               u1.usuuf
  FROM projetos pp
       INNER JOIN tarefa t ON pp.projid = t.projid
       INNER JOIN usuario u ON t.usuidresponsavel = u.usuid
       INNER JOIN usuario u1 ON t.usuidcliente = u1.usuid
       LEFT JOIN statusaux s ON t.tarstatus = s.statusid
       LEFT JOIN complemento c ON c.usuid = t.usuidcliente
                              AND c.compid = 1
 WHERE t.macprocid = 33
   AND t.tartipid IN (866)
```

Comment: Demonstre algum exemplo do resultado que você espera, só com o que está exemplificado de `query` não dá pra entender o que você quer.

Comment: @RenanBessa: No primeiro código, a junção entre as tabelas `tarefa` e `tipo` é do tipo LEFT JOIN mas a presença da restrição `c.tipdescricao LIKE 'Habilita%'` a transforma em INNER JOIN. É isto mesmo que necessita?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avalie o seguinte código.

```
-- código #1 v3
with 
cteUm as (
  SELECT p.projid, tt.tartitulo
    FROM tarefa tt
         INNER JOIN projetos p ON p.projid = tt.projid
         LEFT JOIN tipo c ON c.tipid = tt.tartipid
   WHERE tt.modid = 181
     AND tt.tarstatus <> 9
     AND (tt.tartipid BETWEEN 867 AND 934
          OR tt.tartipid IN (1004, 1034))
     AND c.tipdescricao LIKE 'Habilita%'
),
cteDois as (
SELECT r.projid,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t.tartitulo
                FROM cteUm t
               WHERE t.projid = r.projid
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS operadoras
  FROM cteUm r
  GROUP BY projid
)
SELECT pp.projdesc, pp.projid,
       c.compdesc as qtdecnpjs,
       u1.usuuf, C2.operadoras
  FROM projetos pp
       INNER JOIN tarefa t ON pp.projid = t.projid
       INNER JOIN usuario u ON t.usuidresponsavel = u.usuid
       INNER JOIN usuario u1 ON t.usuidcliente = u1.usuid
       --LEFT JOIN statusaux s ON t.tarstatus = s.statusid
       LEFT JOIN complemento c ON c.usuid = t.usuidcliente
                              AND c.compid = 1
       LEFT JOIN cteDois as C2 on C2.projid = pp.projid
 WHERE t.macprocid = 33
   AND t.tartipid = 866;

--
IF Object_Id('tempDB..#FiltroTarefa', 'U') is not null
  DROP TABLE #FiltroTarefa;
go
```

O SELECT externo do primeiro código é transformado na CTE cteDois.

Me parece que a tabela statusaux não é necessária na consulta externa (a última), principalmente pelo fato da junção ser do tipo OUTER JOIN.

O DISTINCT foi retirado. Se o resultado indicar que é necessário, reinsira-o.

A coluna `projdesc` foi substituída pela coluna `projid` na `cteUm`. É que a comparação pela denominação de objeto nem sempre é confiável quando é possível ter mais de um objeto com o mesmo nome.

Comment: vc realmente é o cara. Valeu, deu td certo!

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer usar a concatenação da primeira `query` para retornar os registros da segunda você teria que fazer o seguinte:

```
WITH tabela (projeto, operadora, compdesc, usuuf) AS (
  SELECT pp.projdesc,
         t.titulo,
         c.compdesc,
         u1.usuuf
  FROM projetos pp
       INNER JOIN tarefa t ON pp.projid = t.projid
       INNER JOIN usuario u ON t.usuidresponsavel = u.usuid
       INNER JOIN usuario u1 ON t.usuidcliente = u1.usuid
       LEFT JOIN statusaux s ON t.tarstatus = s.statusid
       LEFT JOIN complemento c ON c.usuid = t.usuidcliente
                              AND c.compid = 1
 WHERE t.macprocid = 33
   AND t.tartipid IN (866))

SELECT r.projeto,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t.operadora
                FROM tabela t
               WHERE t.projeto = r.projeto

                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS operadoras,
       SUM(r.compdesc) AS qtdecnpjs,
       r.usuff
  FROM tabela r
 GROUP BY r.projeto, r.usuff;
```

Comment: ôpa grande Sorack! Valeu mestre, ajudou bastante.